# Adding a php to a paragraph with a span class

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Still new to all of this, not sure if I'm using span class correctly however, I have to "link" this paragraph to a field groupp in wordpress and im not sure how to modify the code correctly.

This is an example of what was meant to be achieved:

`<h2><?php the_field('barbarismtitle'); ?></h2>`
I can edit this fine in wordpress but Im not sure how I would do the same for this:

`<p>After <span class="thebatavia">The Batavia</span> was wrecked, the survivors were left to the dictatorship of <span class="jeronimuscornelisz">Jeronimus Cornelisz</span>, where 125 men, women and children were murdered.</p>`

The span is so that only a few words in the paragraph have a certain colour. Any help would be appreciated. (also there aren't spaces in my code, It just wouldn't show otherwise)

Answer (score 0):

Using the span to add a custom class to change the colour of the text is a good idea, if your trying to create a link to another page you will need to use an A tag.

so the php needed to link would look something like this

```
<p>After <a href="<?php the_field('barbarismtitle'); ?>">The Batavia</a> was wrecked, the
survivors were left to the dictatorship of.....
```

This is assuming that the_field('barbarismtitle') would return a url to fill the href property

Comment: Thanks v much, I think I didn't give enough information. Attempting to learn how to take a html doc and add it to wordpress, in a manner to allow a client to edit the content but keep the original styling. For this unit ,I've been asked to highlight SEO keywords, so in this instance I'm attempting to keep the previously coloured words (my span words) and at the same time remove as much static content. I will add editable content(the actual wording) to wordpress after . (thank you again so much)